# Swift 2.0: How To Declare Nested Dictionaries?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to do a complex Swift Dictionary declaration similar to a JSON packet. However, the compiler is fighting me tooth and nail. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var icons: [[Any:Any]] = [
    "categories:":[
        ["cat2" : [
            ["name":"ImageName","type":"image"],
            ["name":"ImageName","type":"scroll","panel":panel1],
            ["name":"ImageName","type":"chooser","panel":[
                ["name":"ImageName"]]]
            ]
        ],
        ["cat2" : ["name":"ImageName"]],
        ["cat3" : ["name":"ImageName"]],
        ["cat4" : ["name":"ImageName"]],
        ["cat5" : ["name":"ImageName"]]
    ],
    "size":["x":"128","y":"128"]
]
```

I'm not sure how to declare this. As you can tell, I have the first element as a String, and the following sub elements as additional Dictionaries.

I want to know a best of practice method for these data structures in Swift.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is **NOT** recommended to create such structure in Swift but if you really want to do it, you can create each part separably. Ex. `let subDict = ["cat2" : ["name":"ImageName"]]` and merge them together later

Comment: Gotcha. I'm so surprised that folks don't need this more often. With JSON going on 10 years old and being the standard form of containing data, it baffles me that Swift doesn't have a simple method for this type of declaration. Ty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way is **NOT** to use a dictionary.

You should create a few model types (preferably `structs`) and combine them.

Otherwise managing a dictionary like this will be hell.

Comment: Well that makes sense. This has been hell. ;)

Comment: @MarkLöwe: I believe you :D

Comment: @LucaAngeletti, can You show with an exact example?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you're actually declaring an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary of dictionaries: `[Any:[Any:Any]]`  (or better yet, given your data) `[String:[String:Any]]`  But that won't work because the `categories` key value is actually an array, not a string.  At that point you're left with just `[String:Any]`

The bottom line, however, is that you're going to be much better off taking @appzYourLife's approach and defining appropriate model types.

Comment: Thank you! You're exactly describing my continuous stream of errors. :)